# Running kafka connect in Distributed mode?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, apache-kafka-connect, confluent-platform

I have a total of 3 VM's(CloudVPS). Each of them has java, confluent open source installed on them. In VM1 I am running 3 processes of Splunk-sink-connector which reads from different topics and are running on different ports. And using REST calls I posted JSON configuration to each of them.

Since I am running in distributed mode I want to take advantage of other 2 VM's also. Can anyone please tell me what to do, to add other 2 VM's to those 3 processes to achieve parallel processing.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You just need to run Kafka Connect in Distributed mode on the three VMs, [follow the instructions here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#distributed-mode) and make sure you give them all the same `group.id` which identifies them as members of the same cluster (and thus eligible for sharing workload of tasks out across them). More config details for distributed mode [here](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html#connect-userguide-dist-worker-config).

See also:

- https://rmoff.net/2019/11/22/common-mistakes-made-when-configuring-multiple-kafka-connect-workers/
- http://rmoff.dev/ksldn19-kafka-connect

Comment: Do you have similar document or helm charts for kafka connect distributed modee on kubernetes cluster ?

Comment: is groud.id property still existing in Apache Kafka?